# Dynamic GroupBy and count using Spark Dataframes/Datasets

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset, rdd

The use case is to group by each column in a given dataset, and get the count of that column.
The resulting set is (key, value) map and then finally uinion of them all.
For eg
`students = {(age, firstname, lastname)(12, "FN", "LN"), (13, "df", "gh")}`
`groupby age => (12, 1), (13, 1)`
`groupby firstname => etc`

I know the brute force approach is to do a map and maintain a map for count for each column
but i wanted to see if there is something more we can do with maybe foldLeft and windows function. I tried using rollup and cube but that does groups all column together rather than indivdual

Comment: can you please share sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you need Key, Value, Grouping Column name as three columns in the output, you would have to use the below code so that key and grouping column relationships can be understood.

**Code**

```
val df = Seq(("12", "FN", "LN"),
    ("13", "FN", "gh")).toDF("age", "firstname", "lastname")
df.show(false)

val initialDF = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], StructType(
    Seq(StructField("Key", StringType), StructField("Value", IntegerType), 
    StructField("GroupColumn", StringType))
))

val resultantDf = df.columns.foldLeft(initialDF)((df1, column) => df1.union(
      df.groupBy(column).count().withColumn("GroupColumn", lit(column))
    ))
resultantDf.show(false)

resultantDf.collect().map { row =>
      (row.getString(0), row.getLong(1))
}.foreach(println)
```

**Output**

```
INPUT DF:
+---+---------+--------+
|age|firstname|lastname|
+---+---------+--------+
|12 |FN       |LN      |
|13 |FN       |gh      |
+---+---------+--------+

OUTPUT DF:
+---+-----+-----------+
|Key|Value|GroupColumn|
+---+-----+-----------+
|12 |1    |age        |
|13 |1    |age        |
|FN |2    |firstname  |
|gh |1    |lastname   |
|LN |1    |lastname   |
+---+-----+-----------+

OUTPUT LIST:
(12,1)
(13,1)
(FN,2)
(gh,1)
(LN,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you need Union of the grouped data frames, I was able to solve it as below:

**Code**

```
val df = Seq(("12", "FN", "LN"),
      ("13", "FN", "gh")).toDF("age", "firstname", "lastname")
df.show(false)

val initialDF = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], StructType(
      Seq(StructField("column", StringType), StructField("count", IntegerType))
))

df.columns.foldLeft(initialDF)((df1, column) => df1.union(df.groupBy(column).count())).show(false)
```

**Output**

```
INPUT DF:
+---+---------+--------+
|age|firstname|lastname|
+---+---------+--------+
|12 |FN       |LN      |
|13 |FN       |gh      |
+---+---------+--------+

OUTPUT DF:
+------+-----+
|column|count|
+------+-----+
|12    |1    |
|13    |1    |
|FN    |2    |
|gh    |1    |
|LN    |1    |
+------+-----+
```

Comment: Yes! Thats absolutely what i was looking for. I tried the foldleft but used it wrong i think. Will try this out and see how this performs over just a normal count and maintaining map. I am not too keen on the latter honestly so looking for something concise. Thank you!

Comment: @Patssay- if you are done with the testing, please accept the answer or let me know if you need any help on this.